# I am facing some weird behaviour with pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am quite curious to know why this is happening. I have two images of the same size and almost similar background colors but with different text, pytesseract is unable to extract text from one image but it is doing perfectly with the other? what am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, pytesseract does it's own image processing before doing ocr. I am unsure as to what exactly may cause this but, whatever image processing pytesseract is doing may be the cause of the issue.

I would give easyocr and paddleocr a try to compare results. Those 2 libs expect the user to apply image processing (either using the respective lib or, by the user themself). That should give you more control over the results.